# can i generate soap client from password protected wsdl using eclipse in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to generate web service client for a wsdl which is  password protected.I am using eclipse "Web Service Client" functionality.For Normal WSDL it is working fine,but there is no option to give user name and password in the generation process.How could i achieve this

Comment: WSDL is a file. You can not protect it with a password. Did you mean protect the download of the WSDL with a password?

Comment: yes wsdl with username & password

Comment: Then, generate the WSDL and copy it in a directory of your server  protected by user&pwd

Answer (score 0):

If you used Eclipse "Web Service Client" I think you should have an autogenerated class called something like yourservicenameimpl**Locator**
this will have a method that returns the service port.

Look in this class for something like:

```
 _stub.setPortName
```

here you can add

```
  _stub.setUsername("yourusername");
    _stub.setPassword("yourpassword");
```

Not sure this is the proper way to do it but it should get you going.